# Laravel 5 create user by email list

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> I have full emails of users. I'm trying to validate by that emails. And I'm checking in RegisterController.

**RegisterController@create**

```
protected function create(array $data,Request $request)
{
    $users = Niigem::pluck('email')->toArray();
    $mama = $request->input('email');
    if($mama === $users){
        User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    else{
        dd('incomplete');
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 1 passed in C:\wamp\www\zainsurgalt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 33 and exactly 2 expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Here if the updated function.

You are doing some unnecessary things in you function. so I improved this function

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $isEmailExists = Niigem::where('email', data['email'])->count();
    if($isEmailExists){
        User::create([
        'name'     => data['name'],
        'email'    => data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt(data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    else{
        dd('incomplete');
    }
}
```

I think this will help

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, array given, called in C:\wamp\www\zainsurgalt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 33`

Comment: `Token Mismatch Exception`

Comment: check in register form you have added `{!! csrf_field() !!}`. if already added then refresh page and again submit form.

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\zainsurgalt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35`

Comment: @RukaXing firstly check default register is working or not? if that not working then you did something wrong.

Comment: check again.  because this small error could not clear why you got this error. So best way is to start from scratch. and check step by step your code. That will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180041/discussion-between-lucky-saini-and-ruka-xing).